# Save and load python socket object to sqlite db?

Tags: python, sqlite, sockets

I want to create multiple socket objects and save them in an sqlite database because I dont want to create huge lists of socket objects in my memory. Later(in the same python session) I want to load one socket after another in a var  and use it again to send messages and other stuff. Now my Problem is that im not sure how I can serialize and save it in a sqlite db. I tried it with pickling socket as a string object, but it didnt work to well cause i couldnt load it as a socket type object out of the db. Maybe someone knows a better solution?

EDIT:

The issue is now solved. Thanks for all the help of you! What I do now is that immeaditely after accepting new connections, i get the filedescriptor of the conn_socket with [socket.fileno()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.fileno) and write it as a string to my sqlite database. Then, when i need the socket I get the filedescriptor value of my db and create the socket with [socket.fromfd()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.fromfd). The socket is fully functional and can be created over and over again with this method. So I actually got it to work to not have multiple lists but have one db with all useful stuff of the single connections. BUT the important thing to know is that when I close my pthon program the db is getting deleted because the sockets are getting deleted and closed too. Still it is useful for my case.

Comment: You should probably just store the data necessary to instantiate the socket object and load that and create the socket on the fly. I'm pretty sure you cannot even pickle a socket object, serializing something like a socket doesn't make much sense

Comment: Thank you! But do you know a method how to reinstantiate the socket with only ip address and port given?

Comment: The same way you connect any (I assume TCP) socket: `import socket; s = socket.socket(); s.connect((host,port))`.

Comment: There's no point in storing file descriptors in an SQLite database. If you've accepted the connections and not disposed of them (e.g. closing, shutting down), they'll still consume memory (more so when you revive them with `socket.fromfd()` again).

Comment: Yes, youre right they still consume memory. But I wanted to have everything in one db, and still I watched and my memory usage didnt increase over the time cause at least the vars got garbage collected. So for my purposes its really enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is not going to work the way you want. A socket object contains an operating system that's very like an open file. If you save it to a database, you might store some useful information, but the *file* will go away. When you select it from the database then it won't be a working socket anymore.

If you need to have a lot of sockets open, then you just do. They don't actually take all that much storage. If you're worried about it, then close a socket when you're done with it and open another one.

Comment: Thanks!!  But I got one other idea: Do you know how to reinitialize a socket by giving a func a port and Ip? Then I could just save the IP and Port in the db and reinitialize the socket when i need it.

Comment: Sure. Save IP and port and call `socket.socket`, then call connect. That's what they do.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html